# Transition color of element in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, colors, transition

I have 2 scenes in React. On scene 1, there is a div with a timer which color should be transitioned from green to red for 180 seconds. The problem is that at any time user can switch to scene 2 and switch back to the scene1 after some time. So I need a way to start the animation not from the beginning but from the color it would've transitioned after user switched to scene 2, spent some time there and switched back to scene 1.

For example:

1. user opened scene 1
2. user spent 40 seconds there, color transitioned to some orangish one
3. user switched to scene 2 and spent 30 seconds there and then switched back to scene 1

So I need some js magic that can transition color so that the transition starts from the color that would've been there if user spent 70 seconds on scene 1 and the transition time would be 110 seconds. All I can think up for now is some library that can transition colors and in which I can specify the start time from which the transition starts (in time or percentage, it doesn't matter), but I can't find it for now. If you know any other way, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried?

Comment: There was no code. It was done in CSS at first, but after the app got cut in 2 scenes which are routed with react-router the css transitions restart because components mount/unmount on switching.

Answer (score 0):

I made everything work somehow. All I've done is save and get elapsed time when needed via props, calculate needed color hue (from 120 - green, to 0 - red) based on elapsed time, making a setTimeout for a method which changes the current hue in the state and it will just update the needed div color hue value of HSL set div color every second. Additional 1s CSS color transition is used to smooth color changes.